# display selected extjs timefiled and datepicker values together

Tags: extjs

```
 items: [{
         xtype: 'form',
         stype: {
             marginTop: '10px'
         },
         layout: {
             type: 'hbox'
         },
         items: [{
             xtype: 'form',
             layout: {
                 type: 'vbox'
             },
             defaults: {
                 labelAlign: 'top',
                 width: 150
             },
             items: [{
                 xtype: 'button',
                 cls: 'datePickerSearchBtn',
                 text: 'Today',
                 listeners: {
                     click: function() {
                         // when clicking on this button need to set value to today in my datepicker
                     }
                 }
             }, {
                 xtype: 'button',
                 cls: 'datePickerSearchBtn',
                 text: 'Yesterday',
                 listeners: {
                     click: function() {
                         // when clicking on this button need to set value to yesterday in my datepicker
                         this.up('timeIntervalPanel').down('[name=startHourCombo]').reset();
                         this.up('timeIntervalPanel').down('[name=endHourCombo]').reset();
                     }
                 }
             }, {
                 xtype: 'button',
                 cls: 'datePickerSearchBtn',
                 text: 'Last 7 days',
                 listeners: {
                     click: function() {
                         this.up('timeIntervalPanel').setDates(Ext.Date.add(new Date(), Ext.Date.DAY, -7), new Date());
                         this.up('timeIntervalPanel').down('[name=startHourCombo]').reset();
                         this.up('timeIntervalPanel').down('[name=endHourCombo]').reset();
                     }
                 }
             }, {
                 xtype: 'button',
                 cls: 'datePickerSearchBtn',
                 text: 'Last Month',
                 listeners: {
                     click: function() {
                         this.up('timeIntervalPanel').setDates(Ext.Date.add(new Date(), Ext.Date.MONTH, -1), new Date());
                         this.up('timeIntervalPanel').down('[name=startHourCombo]').reset();
                         this.up('timeIntervalPanel').down('[name=endHourCombo]').reset();
                     }
                 }
             }]
         }, {
             xtype: 'form',
             border: true,
             layout: {
                 type: 'vbox',
                 align: 'center'
             },
             items: [{
                     xtype: 'container',
                     layout: 'hbox',
                     margin: '0 0 20 0',
                     items: [{
                         title: 'Start Date',
                         margin: '0 20 0 0',
                         header: {
                             titleAlign: 'center'
                         },
                         items: {
                             xtype: 'datepicker',
                             itemId: 'startDate',
                             value: Ext.Date.add(new Date(), Ext.Date.DAY, -1),
                             showToday: false,
                             handler: function(picker, date) {

                                 var timeInterval = this.up('timeIntervalPanel');
                                 var endDate = timeInterval.endDate;
                                 //timeInterval.setDates(date, endDate);

                                 var oneDay = 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000;
                                 var diffDays = Math.round(Math.abs((endDate.getTime() - date.getTime()) / (oneDay)));
                                 if (diffDays > 29) {
                                     this.up('timeIntervalPanel').down('[name=startHourCombo]').disable();
                                     this.up('timeIntervalPanel').down('[name=text]').disable();
                                     this.up('timeIntervalPanel').down('[name=endHourCombo]').disable();
                                 } else {
                                     this.up('timeIntervalPanel').down('[name=startHourCombo]').enable();
                                     this.up('timeIntervalPanel').down('[name=text]').enable();
                                     this.up('timeIntervalPanel').down('[name=endHourCombo]').enable();
                                 }
                             }

                         }
                     }, {

                         title: 'End Date',
                         margin: '0 20 0 0',
                         header: {
                             titleAlign: 'center'
                         },
                         items: {
                             xtype: 'datepicker',
                             itemId: 'endDate',
                             value: Ext.Date.add(new Date(), Ext.Date.DAY, -1),
                             showToday: false,
                             handler: function(picker, date) {

                                 var timeInterval = this.up('timeIntervalPanel');
                                 var startDate = timeInterval.startDate;
                                 //timeInterval.setDates(startDate, date);

                                 var oneDay = 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000;
                                 var diffDays = Math.round(Math.abs((date.getTime() - startDate.getTime()) / (oneDay)));
                                 if (diffDays > 30) {
                                     this.up('timeIntervalPanel').down('[name=startHourCombo]').disable();
                                     this.up('timeIntervalPanel').down('[name=text]').disable();
                                     this.up('timeIntervalPanel').down('[name=endHourCombo]').disable();

                                 } else {
                                     this.up('timeIntervalPanel').down('[name=startHourCombo]').enable();
                                     this.up('timeIntervalPanel').down('[name=text]').enable();
                                     this.up('timeIntervalPanel').down('[name=endHourCombo]').enable();
                                 }
                             }

                         }
                     }]
                 },
                 {
                     xtype: 'container',
                     layout: 'hbox',
                     items: [{
                             margin: '0 20 0 0',
                             items: {
                                 xtype: 'timefield',
                                 name: 'startHourCombo',
                                 id: 'startTime',
                                 maxWidth: 100,
                                 columnWidth: 0.2,
                                 minValue: '12:00 AM',
                                 maxValue: '11:00 PM',
                                 increment: 60,
                                 anchor: '100%',
                                 value: '12:00 AM',
                                 disabled: false,
                                 listeners: {
                                     change: function() {
                                         var timeIntervalPanel = this.up('timeIntervalPanel');
                                         timeIntervalPanel.setDates(timeIntervalPanel.startDate, timeIntervalPanel.endDate);
                                     }
                                 }

                             }
                         }, {
                             margin: '0 20 0 0',
                             items: {
                                 xtype: 'displayfield',
                                 name: 'text',
                                 maxWidth: 80,
                                 minWidth: 30,
                                 columnWidth: 0.2,
                                 value: 'To',
                                 disabled: false
                             }
                         },
                         {
                             xtype: 'timefield',
                             name: 'endHourCombo',
                             id: 'endTime',
                             maxWidth: 100,
                             minValue: '12:00 AM',
                             maxValue: '11:00 PM',
                             increment: 60,
                             anchor: '100%',
                             value: '12:00 AM',
                             disabled: false,
                             listeners: {
                                 change: function() {
                                     var timeIntervalPanel = this.up('timeIntervalPanel');
                                     timeIntervalPanel.setDates(timeIntervalPanel.startDate, timeIntervalPanel.endDate);
                                 }
                             }

                         }
                     ]
                 }
             ]


         }]

     }],

     setDates: function(startDate, endDate) {

         if (!startDate) startDate = new Date();

         if (!endDate) endDate = new Date();

         this.startDate = startDate;
         this.endDate = endDate;

         var startDatePicker = this.down('datepicker#startDate');
         var endDatePicker = this.down('datepicker#endDate');
         var startTime = this.up().down('timefield#startTime');
         var endTime = this.up().down('timefield#endTime');

         startDatePicker.setValue(startDate);
         endDatePicker.setValue(endDate);
         startDatePicker.setMaxDate(endDate);
         endDatePicker.setMinDate(startDate);

         var startDateValue = Ext.Date.format(startDate, 'd-m-Y');
         var endDateValue = Ext.Date.format(endDate, 'd-m-Y');
         this.setText(startDateValue + " " + startTime.getRawValue() + " TO " + endDateValue + " " + endTime.getRawValue());
     }

 });
```

Comment: Your data isn't a valid json object, details needed example problem etc ...

Comment: i want to display default extjs timefield values, when user selects date form date picker and time from my timefield , want to display both values together date and time

Comment: Where you need to display those values ??

Comment: i have a selector button which displays currently selected date from  datepicker and now i want to display time also which is selected from  time field  @ankitchaudhary

Comment: Then share the code of your selector button

Comment: i have posted my code ,using setDates function displaying the selected date on selector button now i also want display selected time on selector button @ankitchaudhary

Answer (score 0):

Just call the `setDates()` in change event of both timefields and get the values of those timefields and add it in `setText()` of button.

**Sample Code:**

```js
Ext.application({
  name: 'Fiddle',
  launch: function() {
    Ext.create('Ext.form.Panel', {
      border: true,
      renderTo: Ext.getBody(),
      layout: {
        type: 'hbox'
      },
      listeners: {
        afterrender: function(button) {
          button.setDates();
        }
      },
      setDates: function(startDate, endDate) {
        if (!startDate) startDate = new Date();

        if (!endDate) endDate = new Date();

        this.startDate = startDate;
        this.endDate = endDate;

        var startDatePicker = this.down('datepicker#startDate');
        var endDatePicker = this.down('datepicker#endDate');

        startDatePicker.setValue(startDate);
        endDatePicker.setValue(endDate);
        startDatePicker.setMaxDate(endDate);
        endDatePicker.setMinDate(startDate);

      },
      items: [{
          xtype: 'container',
          layout: {
            type: 'vbox',
            align: 'center'
          },
          defaults: {
            labelAlign: 'top',
            width: 150
          },
          items: [{
            xtype: 'button',
            cls: 'datePickerSearchBtn',
            text: 'Today',
            listeners: {
              click: function() {
                // when clicking on this button need to set value to today in my datepicker
              }
            }
          }, {
            xtype: 'button',
            cls: 'datePickerSearchBtn',
            text: 'Yesterday',
            listeners: {
              click: function() {
                // when clicking on this button need to set value to yesterday in my datepicker
                this.up('form').down('[name=startHourCombo]').reset();
                this.up('form').down('[name=endHourCombo]').reset();
              }
            }
          }, {
            xtype: 'button',
            cls: 'datePickerSearchBtn',
            text: 'Last 7 days',
            listeners: {
              click: function() {
                this.up('form').setDates(Ext.Date.add(new Date(), Ext.Date.DAY, -7), new Date());
                this.up('form').down('[name=startHourCombo]').reset();
                this.up('form').down('[name=endHourCombo]').reset();
              }
            }
          }, {
            xtype: 'button',
            cls: 'datePickerSearchBtn',
            text: 'Last Month',
            listeners: {
              click: function() {
                this.up('form').setDates(Ext.Date.add(new Date(), Ext.Date.MONTH, -1), new Date());
                this.up('form').down('[name=startHourCombo]').reset();
                this.up('form').down('[name=endHourCombo]').reset();
              }
            }
          }]
        },
        {
          xtype: 'container',
          layout: {
            type: 'vbox',
            align: 'center'
          },
          items: [{
              xtype: 'container',
              layout: 'hbox',
              margin: '0 0 20 0',
              items: [{
                title: 'Start Date',
                margin: '0 20 0 0',
                items: {
                  xtype: 'datepicker',
                  value: Ext.Date.add(new Date(), Ext.Date.DAY, -1),
                  itemId: 'startDate',
                  showToday: false,
                  handler: function(picker, date) {
                    var timeIntervalPanel = this.up('form');
                    var endDate = timeIntervalPanel.endDate;
                    timeIntervalPanel.setDates(date, endDate);
                  }
                }
              }, {

                title: 'End Date',
                margin: '0 20 0 0',
                items: {
                  xtype: 'datepicker',
                  itemId: 'endDate',
                  value: Ext.Date.add(new Date(), Ext.Date.DAY, -1),
                  showToday: false,
                  handler: function(picker, date) {
                    var timeIntervalPanel = this.up('form');
                    var startDate = timeIntervalPanel.startDate;
                    timeIntervalPanel.setDates(startDate, date);
                  }
                }
              }]
            },
            {
              xtype: 'container',
              layout: 'hbox',
              margin: '0 20 0 0',
              items: [{
                  xtype: 'timefield',
                  name: 'startHourCombo',
                  id: 'startTime',
                  minValue: '12:00 AM',
                  maxValue: '11:00 PM',
                  increment: 60,
                  value: '12:00 AM',
                },
                {
                  xtype: 'timefield',
                  name: 'endHourCombo',
                  id: 'endTime',
                  minValue: '12:00 AM',
                  maxValue: '11:00 PM',
                  increment: 60,
                  value: '11:00 PM',
                }
              ]
            },
          ]
        }
      ]
    });
  }


});
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.sencha.com/ext/gpl/4.1.1/resources/css/ext-all.css">
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdn.sencha.com/ext/gpl/4.1.1/ext-all-debug.js"></script>
```

Comment: thank you and if i want to include buttons like last month and last week and last year to get values from date picker and display on selector button in the same above example how can i do that can you help me out please

Comment: In Same Button or a different button?? Just give an example how it should be displayed.

Comment: i have replaced code in my  question @ankitchaudhary

Comment: and added an image how my componnet should be look like, can you help me out please @ankitchaudhary

Comment: in my code mentioned in question getting error like can't read property startDate and endDate, can you tell me where i am doing wrong @ankitchaudhary

Comment: As per the image, I don't see you are displaying the selected date on any selector button and as per your code, it has errors because you just copied my code and placed in yours code, I don't see where you have defined `timeIntervalPanel` xtype.

Comment: removed selector button right now displaying the new component other panel as using timeIntervalPanel xtype can help me what the errors in my code

Comment: As told earlier, I am getting error in your as `timeIntervalPanel` is not defined. Can you tell in which line you are getting error??

Comment: no my doubt is how to add buttons in your code only like today,yesterday,last 7 days,last month and clicking on those buttons set values from datepicker

Comment: thank you and if i dont want the xtype button to display selected date range what changes should i make in handler functions " var timeIntervalPanel = this.up('form').down('button#timeIntervalPanel') "  can you please help me

Comment: hi can you help me out if i dont want xtype: 'button'  "timeIntervalPanel" how to replace the code in handler and listeners and how to use the setdates function please help me out

Comment: in my case i am getting error setDates is not a function https://fiddle.sencha.com/#view/editor&fiddle/27u8 i posted my code in this fiddle can you help me where i am doing wrong

Comment: Your code has multiple form.Give an item id to outermost form and then use `this.up('form[itemId=<formItemId>]')` instead of `this.up('form')`. Or just change all inner forms into panel.

Comment: how to get current GMT+14 time to set maxDate for the datepicker